# Getting users data from same field

Tags: php, mysql

So, I'm writing an application in PHP and I'm trying to retrieve unique user data based on what they entered. Here is my code:

```
function hello($username123) {
   // Connect to Database //
$host3     = "db"; 
$username3 = "db"; 
$password3 = "db"; 
$db3       = "db";
$con3 = mysqli_connect($host3,$username3,$password3,$db3) or die("Can not connect to Server.");
$student1name; 
$query3 = mysqli_query($con3,"SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'username' = '$username123' and '$student1name' = 'student1'");
return "$student1name";

}
```

So, the user enters there username which they registered earlier on and then I run a query where the username field is equal to the username variable (The input) and that the student1name variable is equal to the student1 field where the username is the same as the one entered. I then return the student1name variable. But when I test this all that returns is "". I can't figure out the problem

Comment: You can't set a PHP-variable in a SQL-query!

Comment: Also, what is the 8th line ( `$student1name;` ) supposed to do? You can delete that altogether. If you read a couple of PHP and MySQLi tutorials in depth they will greatly help you.

Comment: Several problems already identified in answers below. You need to fetch the results from the query. The code you have executes a statement, but doesn't fetch from the resulset (which would be produced if the SQL were valid.) Since you need one column, replace that * with the name of the column you want to retrieve data from. Don't use single quotes around identifiers, use backtick characters. And most importantly, use prepared statement, or at least sanitize the input values. Beware of Little Bobby Tables, whose username is "`Robert'; DROP TABLES users; --`"

Comment: To be honest, I'm really new to PHP and MySQL. I've done all you said, and I don't know what's invalid about my SQL.Could you please point out where the code is wrong and what to add to simply return the student's name. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

you are not fetching the results of the query, try something like this after your query..

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query3, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

return $row['studentname'];
```

i'm assuming the student's name is in a column called studentname in your DB

Answer (score 0):

You must bind the result in a result array and access it like that, something like this should work:

```
return $query3["student1name"];
```

Would probably be more effective.

If you're only selecting ONE variable in your query then you can simply echo $query3.

It would also be more effective if you'd look into prepared statements.

Note that

```
$student1name
```

doesn't do anything since you never give it a proper value.

Comment: Doesn't return anything

Comment: Try "SELECT student1name FROM"... and then just return $query3; And give $student1name some value.

Comment: Thats the entire problem.. what value will I give $student1name

Comment: Please Help, It would mean a lot!

Comment: You got it wrong, you don't pass the value to $student1name, you don't do anything with it. 'student1' = '$student1name' means, if the row student1 is equal to the variable $student1name, which is ... nothing. You never give it value. Instead you want to do something like: $student1name = mysqli_query($con3,"SELECT student1 FROM users WHERE username = '$username123'");

Answer (score 0):

PHP automatically replaces any variables you use inside a string to the value of that variable.  For example, if $student1name = 'foo' then putting $student1name anywhere in your SELECT statement literally outputs you a string 'foo' in place of that variable.  As far as the mysqli statement is concerned, you aren't using a PHP value, you are using a literal string 'foo'.  Therefore, expecting your $student1name var to magically change based on the sql statement isn't going to happen.

To retrieve a column's value you will need to fetch the result rows after you perform the query:

```
if ($row = $query3->fetch_assoc()) {
  return $row["student1"];
}
```

If you are expecting more than one result row, then you just need to call fetch_assoc() again for each row until it returns you nothing (marking the end of the result rows).

Comment: Do you mean student1 or $student1name?